# How to rename keys in sequence of maps in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have the following structure

```
(def aaa '({:a "read" :b "one"} {:a "open" :b "two"}) )
```

I need to rename all **:a** keys for example to **:c** and I want to get

```
({:c "read" :b "one"} {:c "open" :b "two"})
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for `clojure.set`'s [rename-keys](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.set/rename-keys) function.
Used with `map`, you'll get the result you want:

```
(map #(clojure.set/rename-keys % {:a :c}) [{:a "read" :b "one"} {:a "open" :b "two"}])
=> ({:b "one", :c "read"} {:b "two", :c "open"})
```